# Aura set an attribute on a standard HTML tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am developing an Aura component that uses an external library which relies on using the `Element.setAttribute()` method.

When I call the following code inside the controller: `element.setAttribute("disabled", true);`

I get this error in console:

`SecureElement: [object HTMLDivElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } does not allow setting the disabled attribute, ignoring!`

I suppose it has something to do with Locker Service. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach will be to use an attribute to disable the element and set the attribute value from the controller.

```
<aura:attribute name="disableElement" type="Boolean" />
```

Whatever element you are trying to disable just bind the above attribute to it.

```
 <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disableElement}"...
```

Now you can control it by the value of the attribute.

### Update

If you don't want to use so many attributes to disable the elements, you can use an attribute of type object, and put one property for each element.

For example

```
<lightning:button disabled="{!v.disableSetting.disableButtonA}"...
```

You will need to set the default value to the attribute as an empty object.

Comment: This is the approach I am going for right now, though I don't like dirtying the component with these attributes. There are a lot of elements I need to call setAttribute on so I just wanted to keep that logic in JS.

Comment: @MichaelMunta you can create a single object attribute and put all the disabled values in that instead of creating a separate attribute for each of the elements.

Comment: I tried doing it this way, but it simply won't work with aura attributes. The library wants to actually *remove* the disabled attribute from the HTML element. I can't do this with static attributes.

Comment: As a matter of fact, ignore my last comment, I found the issue. Setting the disabled attribute on elements removes the custom classes for some reason and it is a reported issue for Aura components. Check here https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDV7QAM&title=custom-css-classes-are-removed-when-toggling-lightning-button-enabled-state